# How to create stacked column chart using highchart.js with dynamic values

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, pivot, dynamic-columns

```
Table
```

:
Array(4)
0
:
{MonthsName: 'April', AUTOLIV: 0, Continental: 0, Herman miller: 0, REL: 0, …}
1
:
{MonthsName: 'July', AUTOLIV: 0, Continental: 4, Herman miller: 0, REL: 0, …}
2
:
{MonthsName: 'June', AUTOLIV: 1, Continental: 0, Herman miller: 0, REL: 0, …}
3
:
{MonthsName: 'May', AUTOLIV: 1, Continental: 0, Herman miller: 1, REL: 1, …}
length
:
4
[[Prototype]]
:
Array(0)
[[Prototype]]
:
Object

This is my result getting from db after doing PIVOT function

Month Name should come as x-axis and Other column should come as stacked values with its count.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to map your data to the series structure required by Highcharts. You can do that for example in this way:

```
const data = [{
    MonthsName: 'April',
    AUTOLIV: 0,
    Continental: 0,
    'Herman miller': 0,
    REL: 0
  },
  ...
];

const xKey = 'MonthsName';
const series = {};
const chartSeries = [];

data.forEach((dataObj, index) => {
  for (let key in dataObj) {
    if (key !== xKey) {
      if (index === 0) {
        series[key] = {
          name: key,
          data: []
        };
      }
      series[key].data.push({
        name: dataObj[xKey],
        y: dataObj[key]
      });
    }
  }
});

for (let key in series) {
  chartSeries.push(series[key]);
}

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      stacking: 'normal'
    }
  },
  series: chartSeries
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/esj6hun5/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.data